# Lift (Mongo)Record field auto-computed from another field

Tags: mongodb, lift, lift-mapper, lift-record

I have a field that holds a datetime as well as a denormalization field to store that same datetime value as a unix timestamp (for reasons that are beyond my control at the moment).

I would like the timestamp field to always be in sync with the "main" datetime field and preferrably even be not writable from outside the methods of that record class (but still be readable and queryable).

I've looked at both [`LifecycleCallbacks`](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/net/liftweb/record/LifecycleCallbacks.html) (which should work according some older documentation but now is meant to be used with `Field` types not `Record` types) as well as for a special [`Field`](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/net/liftweb/record/Field.html) type (e.g. `AutoField` or `ComputedField`) to no avail.

Should I look into implementing a custom `Field`, or am I overlooking something obvious? I'm on version [Lift 2.6-M2](http://liftweb.net/26_m2).

```scala
class Job private() extends MongoRecord[Job] with ObjectIdKey[Job] {
  ...
  object regDate extends JodaTimeField(this)
  object regDateUnixtime extends LongField(this)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```scala
private object regDateUnixtime extends LongField(this)

object regDate extends JodaTimeField(this) {

  override def setBox(in: Box[DateTime]) = {
    super.setBox(in) map { v => 
      regDateUnixtime(v.getMillis) 
      v
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: That `foreach` is there just to take advantage of `Box`, right? But yeah, I think that would work—not sure why I didn't think of it. I'll mark this as Accepted as soon as I've successfully implemented it in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. setBox returns a Box representing the field's value after the method completes.  The forEach would "open" the Box and set your companion field, provided the set operation succeeds.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... I personally find using `foreach` extremely unintuitive/unreadable for monads that only ever contain up to a single item; I'd much rather see Scala introduce an alias for e.g. `Option.foreach` called `ifNonEmpty` or `use` or something... But of course that's another topic. As a compromise, I use `map` (because it doesn't linguistically imply the presence of more than 1 item to the reader), but of course it's far from perfect either.

Comment: Actually, map is more appropriate here anyway since the override still needs to return the boxed value.  I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `regDateUnixtime.setBox(v.getMillis)`? And in any case, will this work for both the non-mutating `job.regDate(...)` as well as the mutating `job.regDate.set(...)`?

Comment: In this case v is the value inside the box, which I believe is a Joda DateTime.  Calling getMillis on it will give you a Long, which you'd have to re-Box in order to call setBox on the companion field.  It wouldn't work for apply on an immutable Record this way, but you could override apply to get the same effect.  I think you get the general idea.